# "Sharing violation on path..." in Xamarin in OnCreate()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Working on an Android app in C#. Trying to access and edit a file every time onCreate() is called. (OnCreate() calls updateTileInstallationStatus())

```
           private void updateTileInstallationStatus()
           {

                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("tileData.xml"))) { 
                            XmlDocument xmlDoc = setAllTilesUninstalled(streamReader);
                            //some file editing here...
                            xmlDoc.Save(getFilePath());
                }
            }

            private XmlDocument setAllTilesUninstalled(StreamReader streamReader) 
            {
                //use template from Assets to set all tile installation status as false
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument ();
                xmlDoc.Load (streamReader);
                xmlDoc.Save(getFilePath());
                return xmlDoc;
            }
```

It successfully saves the file the first time the app is hydrated, but throws a "Sharing violation on path... " upon reopening the app after navigating away.

In other posts, it looks like the problem was solved by closing the StreamReader. I tried doing this after the Save call in updateTile...() but that didn't solve the problem. Same thing with the using statement. It seems like the stream isn't getting closed, and then when updateTile..() gets called for the second time, it can't access the file because it's locked?

Any suggestions on a better way to access/edit the document or close the stream?

Comment: is the sharing violation occurring when you read from the source file or write to the destination file?

Comment: The sharing violation occurs on the call to xmlDoc.save(...). It doesn't throw a violation the first two times this is called (once in updateTiles, and again in setAllTiles, but it's the same xmlDoc object that gets passed as a parameter). The exception is thrown on the save call after I've made a new xmlDocument object and tried to save.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: had an open stream from another method that I never closed, and this prevented me from saving.